# systemd service: As which user is the EnvironmentFile directive read?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I have a systemd service with a config like:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=example systemd service unit file.

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/program
EnvironmentFile=/etc/program.conf
User=someuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now the question is, which user is the `EnvironmentFile` read as? As `root` or as `someuser`? The docs aren't very clear, but I found text saying:

> The files listed with this directive will be read shortly before the process is executed (more specifically, after all processes from a previous unit state terminated. This means you can generate these files in one unit state, and read it with this option in the next. The files are read from the file system of the service manager, before any file system changes like bind mounts take place).

So the bind mounts probably need to happen as `root`. Does that mean I can assume that the EnvironmentFile is read as `root`, since it's read before the bind mounts?

I can experiment, but I'm a little surprised the docs aren't clearer on this. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I can confirm that the `EnvironmentFile` is read as `root`. So even if the `EnvironmentFile` is owned by `root` and has permissions like `0600`, the defined environment variables are set in a process run as `User=someuser`.